# How show image in php from a mysql search

Tags: php, mysql

I started programming PHP. Until I'm enjoying, but for now things are still a bit confused.

I can record and display images from the database. However I'm trying to do a search through a dropdown, but I am not able to show anything.

Could you possibly help me saying where I am failing please?

If in test2.php I do a search to the last record of the database I can see the image. But if I try to drill through an id of my choice that no longer works.

I apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you all very much.

---

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
     <?php 
    include('config.php'); 
    $query_parent = mysql_query("SELECT idTask from Tasks") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
    ?>
    <body style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '*****';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $idTask = $_POST['idTask'];
$_POST['idTask'] = ctype_digit( (string) $_POST['idTask']) ? (int) $_POST['idTask'] : 0;
$_GET['idTask'] = ctype_digit( (string) $_GET['idTask']) ? (int) $_GET['idTask'] : 0;
    echo"<img src='test2.php?image=". $_POST['idTask'] ."'>";
     if (!isset($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) 
                echo "";
            else{
                $image=  addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
                $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

            if($image_size==FALSE)
                echo "That's not an image";
            else{
                mysql_query("select * from tasks where idTask = '". $_POST['idTask'] ."'");

               echo"<img src='test2.php?image=". $_POST['idTask'] ."'>";

            }

            }


    mysql_close($conn);
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
```

---

**test2.php**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*****") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('Database') or die (mysql_error());

$result= mysql_query("select * from tasks where idTask = ". $_GET['idTask']);

if( mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
    //No image found...

} else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $image = $row['image'];
    header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
    echo $image;
}
?>
```

---

When I do a search, a page appears blank.

[image]

Comment: **WARNING** You're using a deprecated database API. & you're also open to SQL Injections

Comment: I know. I'm learning php. This page is for tests...But thank you very much for your reply,

Answer (score 1):

You've a few mistakes, mainly with array index names.

- Your `mysql` query is using `ididTask`, which never has a value. (in both files)

```
mysql_query("select * from tasks where idTask = '". $_POST['idTask'] ."'");
```

- `$idTask` gets its value from a key with spaces in it, but your form doesn't submit any names with spaces in it.

```
$idTask = $_POST['idTask'];
```

- I would redo your image call to be something like the following, and edit `test2.php` respectively (to use `GET` and not `POST`)

```
echo"<img src='test2.php?image=". $_POST['idTask'] ."'>";
```

- No need for a `while` in `test2.php`. If you adopt the previous point, change your whole file to become something like

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('Database') or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("select * from tasks where idTask = ". $_GET['idTask']);

if( mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
    //No image found...

} else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $image = $row['image'];
    header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
    echo $image;
}
?>
```

- I would secure your `$_GET`/`$_POST` with a simple check

```
$_POST['idTask'] = ctype_digit( (string) $_POST['idTask']) ? (int) $_POST['idTask'] : 0;
$_GET['idTask'] = ctype_digit( (string) $_GET['idTask']) ? (int) $_GET['idTask'] : 0;
```

- I would encode the image before you insert into the database with `base64_encode()`. Then, in `test2.php` use;

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$image = base64_decode($row['image']);
header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I made the changes that you said. But isn't sill working :S

Comment: @rpirez what is the content of `$row['image']`?

Comment: Is an image. a Blob type in Mysql database.
if I do this "select * from tasks where idtask = '201400040'" it's works. But if I want to made a search in dropdown isn't work :S

Comment: Before `if (!isset($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))` add `echo"<img src='test2.php?idTask=". $_POST['idTask'] ."'>";`. It seems like in your main file you were in the middle of doing a file upload, but changed?

Comment: I'm updated my code with your code in my question. Can you see? But don't happen anything :(

Comment: Now you've no form to POST, haha - may need to fix that. From  your comment on the other answer, it looks like there is an encoding issue. Before insertion use `base64_encode` and after `base64_decode`. Just out of curiosity, does it show a broken image "image"?

Comment: I added form to POST yet, but still not working. In other answer you know how to fix that error?

Comment: @rpirez Yes, use `base64_encode` on insert, and `base64_decode` on retrieval.

Comment: Like that? <img src=data:image/jpeg;base64/<?php echo $res['image'];?>"/> ?

Comment: very thanks for your help, but still not working. I don't understant this :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62174/discussion-between--and-rpirez).

Comment: Do you have Skype (purely for IM'ing)? I can help you later tonight, after work (in about 8 hours time)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will contact you later ;) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using ajax it may help you.
this is retrieve hero name from the data base to the drop down list.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("hero");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function showdetails(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str==0)
  { 
 alert("please select an hero");
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("showresult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","details.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
Hero Name:<select name="id" id="id" onchange="showdetails(this.value)">
                <option value="0">Select Hero Name</option>
                <?php

                $sql="select id,name from herophoto";
                $qry=mysql_query($sql);
                $num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
                if($num>0)
                {
                    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $res['id'];?>"><?php echo $res["name"];?></option>
                 <?php
                }
                }
                 ?>
             </select>
             <div id="showresult" align="justify"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the details.php which show you the image what you select from the drop downlist.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("hero");
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$sql="select * from herophoto where id='$id'";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
if($num>0)
{
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
?>
<img src="photo/<?php echo $res['photo'];?>" height="300" width="300"/>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try the code that you give me, but give me an error. Don't show image. show multiple characteres. 0����k��$E��i�k���pg����d�b���d�P4�Ÿ�����E#�,����t�C��:�4��H���Y��A�_I����_|�s��'���0ϥ���"_(H,��w�#���PG��%,��~"��5�ʓn�_���B�/���we�������������=O�M��k韲�Û�� �)��S}��+����b�?eˍ;P�żEas��}j�q\��y�1��/�Ѱ-�$�ܮ